# Unable to upload project to AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to use the Eclipse Java Toolkit. I am using **Java-11**. I followed the instructions on the AWS [website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/getting-started.html) to install Eclipse and the Toolkit.
I am trying to follow a [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/lambda-tutorial.html) but I keep getting below error.

[image]

I have just connected 
AWS Lambda --> Upload Function to AWS Lambda, here provided my function and Region name, then in next window provided, IAM Role and S3 Bucket details. After finishing getting the above error.